# Invalid public ssh key

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

Trying to follow the instructions on github for [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for windows.

I run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@email.com"`, enter passphrase and it appears the SSH key is generated correctly.

However, when trying to "Add SSH Key" on GitHub it gives me the error

> Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-rsa' or 'ssh-dss'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key

The public key generated by Windows looks like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, my@email.com"
*public key*
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Most notably it does not begin with 'ssh-rsa' or 'ssh-dss'. I tried just copying the `*public key*` part and prepending 'ssh-rsa' to it but I get the same error on GitHub. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would argue that GitHub is a tool used primarily for programming and therefore this question is applicable for stackoverflow. However, I will move to superuser if enough votes are cast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it. The public key should look like this:

```
ssh-rsa *public key* my@email.com
```

That is:

```
ssh-rsa<space><public key ending with ==><space><email address>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Linux,after executing the above command,(xyz.pub) file will be generated in the directory you are working on. 
Then if you do a " ***cat xyz.pub*** ", you will get your public key which has "ssh-rsa" in the beginning. [image: This is how it looks like]
Now,you need to copy paste the displayed text in your GitHub Account. 
Hope this will probably solve the issue.
And in windows,I think you should edit the file in NotePad++

Answer (score 1):

GitHub generates two files: one with no type, and one .pub. **You need the second one** with the **`.pub` extension**, that file will already have the pattern:

`ssh-rsa <key> <email>`

If it doesn't have this pattern, you may be looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

After the [Git Bash steps](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), I went through the steps successfully. A pub file was generated in the Drive:\Users<YOUR DIR>.ssh\
Open the file with notepad, copied and pasted into https://github.com/settings/keys. That's it!